# Xcode: Convert to modern Obj-C issue

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am converting my project to use modern Obj-C. When I try to convert I get following issue :

*entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64*

I do not have any clue about why this is happening.

Could anyone suggest a fix for this issue?

Thanks in advance,
Srinivas

Comment: what do you mean modern obj c? Do you mean swift?

Comment: I mean Objective-C programming language

Comment: Is this an iOS or OSX project? And what os version are you trying to update from/to?

Comment: It is an iOS project.The Base SDK is iOS8.0 and the target is iOS 7.0...